# architecture for get and store api request data

Tags: javascript, php, database, rest, architecture

This is more of a architectural questions. An external platform had product and price information for let's say, books. There is an API available to get this information.

What I read is that it should be possible to create a function in Javascript and connect the Javascript to a page where you want to show the data on my own website. This would mean that for each page request an API-call is made. Since the requested information only changes once a day maximum this does not sound the most efficient solution.

Can someone advise a better solution? Something into the direction of a similar php or javascript function that does the request on the background, schedule an update and import the data into mysql? If so, what language would be most common.

I need the solution for a Joomla/php/mysql environment

Comment: Sounds like your concern is to save multiple API calls for nearly static data. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple idea - fetch and store results from the API (ones you think aren't gonna change in a day), either on disk, or in the database, and later use these stored results to retrieve what you otherwise would've fetched from the API.

Since storing anything in frontend JS across page reloads isn't easy, you need to make use of PHP for that. Based on what's given, you seem to have two ways of calling the API:

- via the frontend JS (no-go)
- via your PHP backend (good-to-go)

Now, you need to make sure your results are synced every (say) 24 hours.

Add a snippet to your PHP code that contains a variable `$lastUpdated` (or something similar), and assign it the "static" value of the current time (NOT using `time()`). Now, add a couple of statements to update the stored results `if` the current time is at least 24 hours greater than `$lastUpdated`, followed by updating `$lastUpdated` to current time.

This should give you what you need with one API call per day.

PS: I'm not an expert in PHP, but you can surely figure out the datetime stuff.

Comment: Lovely Roshnet many thanks. I deepdive into the approach and try to find out how to do this. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a cache, and you're not the first person to run into that problem - so you probably don't need to reinvent the wheel and build your own.

Look into something like [Redis](https://redis.io/).  There's an article on it available here as well: https://www.compose.com/articles/api-caching-with-redis-and-nodejs/

Comment: many thanx Riaan. Seen my skills this sounds as the more complex approach. And I don't have Redis available yet as well. But I did not think of that option. Thanks for sharing!